# How to get the value from a string that returns from a Web API?

Tags: c#

I have a string that returns from a Web API:

example:

```
 string res = "refno=11111&status=0&deldate=2023-07-16"
```

how to get the value of refno, status and deldate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's called a "query string".  You can use `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` to get the pieces, if you don't want to parse the string yourself.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.parsequerystring?view=net-7.0